# Flutter How to make background Carousal image like below image

Tags: flutter, dart, carousel

Is there any package to design below screen like. I tried lot of time on Online to get solution, but i didn't get any solution.

Can any one help me how to develop carosual card like below image ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've used this [carousel slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) package once.

also, this [video](https://youtu.be/JEMx2ax0734) might help. Kind of similar to your needs.

*(I'll update the answer once I get to my computer.)*